# If records is already exist in table then I need to send an error message from Postgres SQL function

Tags: postgresql

I have table : email_table,
column : email.

I need function like If records is already exist in table then I need to send an error message otherwise need to insert record.

MY Database is postgres 9.2

Comment: Do you tried something and it not works ?

Comment: did you try smth like `insert into email_table select ... where not exists (select 1 from email_table where email='the@one')`?..

Comment: I want so an alert message like user email already exist

Answer (score 0):

depending on which columns you want to consider, or maybe all; what you are looking for is achievable using a unique key constraint

http://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/unique.php

Comment: I want add my own exception

Comment: if you want exception, just add unique index on email

Comment: then you should catch the exception thrown by default. See if the error code matches the one you want to consider, and throw your own exception (maybe wrap the original exception inside your custom one). take a look at this to see how you can identify what caused the exception https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html?is-external=true you are probably interested in getErrorCode() to decide if it's the unique constraint error or something else